# Is my procedure correct about sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $\alpha\in(0,2)$, and the sequence
>   $$x_{n+1}=\alpha x_n +(1+\alpha)x_{n-1}  \quad \forall n\geq 1$$
>   Find the limit in terms of $\alpha$, $x_0$  and $x_1$.

Check my work.

If $\alpha=1$, else
$$\begin{align*}
x_{n+1}&=x_n+2x_{n-1} \\
x_{2}&=x_1+2x_{0} \\
x_{3}&=x_2+2x_{1} \\
&\;\;\vdots
\end{align*}$$
implies $\lim=x_1+2x_0$.

If $\alpha=2$, else
$$\begin{align*}
x_{n+1}&=2x_n+3x_{n-1} \\
x_{2}&=2x_1+3x_{0} \\
x_{3}&=2x_2+3x_{1}\\
&\;\;\vdots
\end{align*}$$
implies $\lim=3x_0+x_1+x_{n-1}$.

Comment: Please, **please** don't use MathJax like that! Take a look at how I edited your question - try to follow that manner of formatting in the future!

Comment: I thought $\alpha \in (0,2)$. So why can you take $\alpha = 2$? Do you mean $\alpha \in (0,2]$?

Comment: You're right! α∈(0,2) the intervals is open but I can't find the limit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recurrence relation being $$x_{n+1}=\alpha x_n +(1+\alpha)x_{n-1}$$ its characteristic equation is $$r^2=\alpha r+(1+\alpha)$$ the roots of which being $r_1=-1$ and $r_2=1+\alpha$; so the general solution is $$x_{n+1}=c_1 (\alpha +1)^n+c_2 (-1)^n$$ Applying the conditions for $n=0$ and $n=1$, this becomes $$x_{n+1}=\frac{(x_0+x_1) (\alpha +1)^n+(-1)^n (\alpha  x_0+x_0-x_1)}{\alpha +2}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 1):

We can exploit the recurrence relation as follows (same thing as using the Characteristic polynomial, but a little  neater) :

$$\left\{\begin{aligned} x_{n+1}+x_n&=(\alpha+1)(x_{n}+x_{n-1})=\cdots = (\alpha+1)^n(x_1+x_0)\\ x_{n+1}-(\alpha+1)x_n&=-x_n+(\alpha+1)x_{n-1}=\cdots = (-1)^{n}[x_1-(\alpha+1)x_0].\end{aligned}\right.$$

Multiply the first relation with $(\alpha+1)$ and add to get
$$(\alpha+2)x_{n+1}=(\alpha+1)^{n+1}(x_1+x_0)+(-1)^n[x_1-(\alpha+1)x_0].$$
It is easy to see that the limit exists iff $x_1+x_0=0$ and $x_1-(\alpha+1)x_0=0$ in which case the sequence is constant.